# Freeing the Memory of a list that contain lists

Tags: c, linked-list, free, bucket, radix-sort

I have an assignment where i have to create a radix sort method using linked lists. First i create a sequence/list of random numbers then perform radix sort on the list using a list of 10 buckets. I have managed to create the sequence and buckets for the radix sort method but my problem is freeing/clearing the memory of all the buckets and sequence when im done.
Heres my attempt to clear all the memory for the buckets. Any idea on how to stop the
errors warnings i get at the bottom and free a list of lists properly?

```
Example. Let’s sort the sequence S0 = {32, 100, 11, 554, 626, 122, 87, 963, 265, 108, 9}.
We start by distributing elements of S0 by the value of 0-place digit (the one's place):

bucket 0: 100

bucket 1: 11

bucket 2: 32, 122

bucket 3: 963

bucket 4: 554

bucket 5: 265

bucket 6: 626

bucket 7: 87

bucket 8: 108

bucket 9: 9



ListNode *buckets = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode)*10);

void clearBuckets(ListNode *buckets)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i =0; i< 10; i++)
    {
             if(&buckets[i] !=NULL){
                     if(buckets[i].next!=NULL);
                            deleteList(&buckets[i]);
                     }
             }
    }

}

void radixSort(ListNode *head, ListNode *buckets, int numValues,int place){
ListNode* buck[10]; /*points to location in radArr*/
//head = head->next;
int index;
ListNode*current =head->next;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    buck[i] = &buckets[i];
}

for(int j = 0; j<numValues;j++)
{
    int num = getPlace(place,current->data);
    buck[num] = insertNode(buck[num], current->data);
   //      printf("place:%d\n",num);
    if(j==numValues -1){
            break;
    }
    else{
    current = current ->next;
    }

  }
}


 void freeList(ListNode **head){
 ListNode* current = *head;
 ListNode* next;
 while (current != NULL)
 {
     next = current->next;

     free(current);
     current = next;
  }
*head = NULL;
}

**I get these warnings when i try to run**
***warning: passing argument 1 of ‘freeList’ from incompatible pointer type [- 
Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 freeList(&buckets[i]);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~***

I also get an error when i try to free my sequence which im assuming is because my 
 **freeList** method takes in a ** whereas my sequence is * (just a guess as to why im 
not able to  free a regular single list, im assuming my **freeList** method is out of 
wack as well...)
```

Comment: You have operations of `free` being played on operands starting with `&` all over this code, and every one of them is wrong. By definition, `&anything` is not a dynamic-acquired address, and therefore not subject to `free` (or `realloc`, fwiw).

Comment: I think you want the elements of your `buckets` array to be node pointers of type `ListNode *`, so it should be `ListNode **buckets`.

Comment: (Also, if the input you want to sort is a linked list, you don't need to create and destroy the nodes in the bucket over and over. Just move the existing nodes around. I'm also a bit wary of controlling a linked list with an element count. You can keep a count, but the list manipulation should be done via the links only, in my opinion.)